# Comparing Multiple Schemas

Tags: mysql, vba

I have to compare and sync multiple MySQL database schemas. I do not have to sync the data. Any differences would missing tables or fields in older schemas.

I can write some VBA to do this. I was thinking of following these steps:

```
SHOW TABLES
for each table
    SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}
    Compare this to each other schema
    If table doesn't exist, then create it.
    If it does exist but different then do a DESCRIBE TABLE TO GET THE FIELDS
        Loop though each field to find missing one then do an ALTER TABLE to add it
```

**Currently, there's 54 DBs with 106 tables each.**

Since the newest DB will have the current schema, I'll only have to compare it to each other DB.
What I want to know is if I'm doing this in the most efficient way. Or is there a better way?  3rd party tools are also an option, as long as it can be automated.

Thanks

In case you want to know some of the background:
Each database is a month's worth of billing data that my client does complex analysis on. The analysis is done in MS Access with a lot of queries and VBA.
Access is attached to 1 month at a time, and has code to switch months as needed.

The schemas can get out of sync when my client adds a table or field to a newer DB to aid in his analysis. When he does this, he's been manually making the same mods to prior DBs (prior DBs are still used months and even years later), but sometimes misses one, plus this is time consuming.

Comment: Any foreign keys between tables?

Comment: Good question. No, there's not. Lots of indexes though.

Answer (score 0):

For a project I had to analyze the structure of Access databases. The way I went was to export the definitions in a CSV file from each Access DB, read this into another Access DB and used hat DB to analyze the tables, and queries. I provide you with the export routine. If you need more, please place a comment. The total code base is quite exensive. The databases can have links to other Access databases (linked tables and queries).

> Subroutine ‘listDBdef()’ creates a text file in the database’s directory with the base name of the database, followed by ‘_dbdef.txt’, e.g. ‘MYDB_2015_04_dbdef.txt’.

```
Public Sub listDBdef()
Dim dbs As Database
Dim tbl As TableDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim FileName As String
Dim i, j, sVersion

    sVersion = UCase(InputBox("Enter version", "Export definitions"))
    If (sVersion = "") Then Exit Sub

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    FileName = Mid(dbs.Name, 1, InStrRev(dbs.Name, ".") - 1) + "_" + sVersion + "_dbdef.txt"

    Open FileName For Output As #1
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    With dbs
        Print #1, sVersion
        Print #1, dbs.Name
        ' List all tables and their link, target table and fields '
        For i = 0 To dbs.TableDefs.Count - 1
            Set tbl = dbs.TableDefs(i)
            If (Mid(tbl.Name, 1, 4) <> "MSys") Then
                Print #1, "Table: """ + tbl.Name + """ {"
                If (tbl.Connect <> "") Then
                    Print #1, Chr(9) + "Link: """ + Mid(tbl.Connect, Len(";DATABASE= ")) + """," + IIf(tbl.Fields.Count > 0, "1", "0") + " {"
                    Print #1, Chr(9) + Chr(9) + "Table: """ + tbl.SourceTableName + """"
                    Print #1, Chr(9) + "}"
                End If
                For j = 0 To tbl.Fields.Count - 1
                    Set fld = tbl.Fields(j)
                    Print #1, Chr(9) + "Field: """ + fld.Name + """"
                Next j
                If (tbl.Fields.Count > 0) Then
                    Print #1, Chr(9) + "Records: " + Trim(Str(tbl.RecordCount))
                End If
                Print #1, "}"
            End If
        Next i

    End With
    Close #1
    MsgBox "Ready."
End Sub
```

You have to create a module with this code in every database you want to analyze; maybe it is possible to connect to the database and query it.